# Getting the first and the last key of multi-dimensional arrays in views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm running a function and querying something like the following:

```
{
"Mar 22, 2015": [ ],
"Mar 23, 2015": [,
{
"id": 5,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Do stuff right now",
"description": "Come on man! serious "
}
],
"Mar 24, 2015": [
{
"id": 8,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Do all your taxes",
"description": "Or else you'll owe a bunch of money."
}
],
"Mar 25, 2015": [
{
"id": 2,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Hey you",
"description": "Blah blah"
}
],
"Mar 26, 2015": [
{
"id": 1,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Do something",
"description": "Oh ya!"
}
],
"Mar 27, 2015": [
{
"id": 4,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Remember to do the laundry",
"description": "Oh la la!"
},
{
"id": 11,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Buy a new snowboard",
"description": "blah blah"
},
{
"id": 12,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Create your business plan",
"description": "blah blah"
}
],
"Mar 28, 2015": [ ]
}
```

My array will always contain 7 days. My question is, I want to grab the first and last date (array keys) to output in my view (without having to specific the key value).

Naturally, I'd like to go `{{ $myweek[0] }}` to get `Mar 22, 2015` and `{{ $myweek[6] }}` to get `Mar 28, 2015`. But I know I can't do that with a multi-dimensional array.

How can I get these start and end dates to my week array without having to hardcode in the date?

***Note,*** I'm already running a `FOREACH` loop for this variable to display each date. But I want to grab values outside the foreach...to show the date range. I.e. Tasks from Mar 22, 2015 to Mar 28, 2015, etc.

Comment: I see that `Laravel` use template-engine `Twig`. If so, cannot you use `loop.first` and `loop.last` when looping through your array?

Comment: Laravel's default template engine is `Blade`. Don't want to install a separate package for Twig.

Comment: Fair enough. Thought of Twig because of `{{ }}`.

Comment: What's with the negative votes people??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you get the point with the code below:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    'key1' => array(1,2,3),
    'key2' => array(4,5,6),
    'key3' => array(7,8,9),
    'key4' => array(10,1,12),
    'key5' => array(13,14,15),
);

$keys = array_keys($arr);
echo $keys[0] . ' AND ' . $keys[count($keys)-1];
```

---

**Update:**
If you want to do this in your view, then you have two ways:

1) You need to pass `$keys` to your view and get those keys from there.

2) Without passing keys: (`$arr` is the variable you have passed to your view)

```
{{ array_keys($arr)[0] }}

{{ array_keys($arr)[count($arr)-1] }}
```

Comment: Logic is already done on the controller. I want a way to grab the key on my view. Not have to build a new array. If i was going to do that, I'd just get the start and end dates I need and pass those to my view. ;)

Comment: Like it. Really, I'm only passing in one addition variable - one additional line on my controller. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBarwick I've got a better solution! Check out the last update!

Comment: I like not passing more data to view...going with door number 2. Exactly what I was looking for. I already had the dates in an array. I didn't see the point in re-creating it again just to reference a couple small keys. You rock and helped me learn something new today. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys):

```
<?php
$json = json_decode('{
"Mar 22, 2015": [ ],
"Mar 23, 2015": [
{
"id": 5,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Do stuff right now",
"description": "Come on man! serious "
}
],
"Mar 24, 2015": [
{
"id": 8,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Do all your taxes",
"description": "Or else you\'ll owe a bunch of money."
}
],
"Mar 25, 2015": [
{
"id": 2,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Hey you",
"description": "Blah blah"
}
],
"Mar 26, 2015": [
{
"id": 1,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Do something",
"description": "Oh ya!"
}
],
"Mar 27, 2015": [
{
"id": 4,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Remember to do the laundry",
"description": "Oh la la!"
},
{
"id": 11,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Buy a new snowboard",
"description": "blah blah"
},
{
"id": 12,
"company_id": 1,
"task": "Create your business plan",
"description": "blah blah"
}
],
"Mar 28, 2015": [ ]
}', true);

$keys = array_keys($json);
echo "From ".$keys[0]." to ".$keys[count($keys) - 1];
?>
```

https://eval.in/305839